# Converting a date formated as DD/MM/YYYY to seconds spent from 01/01/1970?

Tags: linux, date

Following command converts date formated as MM/DD/YYYY to seconds.

```
date -d "01/21/2014" +%s
```

How can I convert DD/MM/YYYY formated date to seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct format as the following

```
date '+%m/%d/%Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want epoch seconds, with perl:

```
perl -MTime::Local -we \
'do {@a = split(m|/|,$_); $a[1]--; print timegm(0,0,0,@a)."\n"} for @ARGV' \
01/11/2010
```

Also note that you specify DD/MM/YYYY as format but give an example of MM/DD/YYYY.

Answer (score -1):

```
date -j -f "%d/%m/%Y" "DD/MM/YYYY" "+%s"
```

Comment: Depending on your OS, the -j may not be needed. Try without, but do not try as root, in case you accidentally set the date on your machine :)